# ReactJS: Parent child partial update

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a bit of a trouble getting my head around how i would communicate between my parent and child components in my specific use case.

I have a child component that renders some points using an external lib.

What I'm currently doing is implementing componentDidMount/Update and use the external lib to render the points in **this.props.points** (which is an array provided by the parent component).

Rendering the points involves looping through them and call something like ExternalLib.addPoint(point).

What i would like to do, instead of looping through all the points everytime **this.props.points** changes, is making the parent component add (or remove) individual points to the child component.

Is it React friendly to call something like **this.refs.myChild.addPoint(point)** in the parent component?

Are there other techniques to achieve something like this?

**Update**

Here's some code (https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61366/):

```
const ExternalLib = {

    addPoint: function(el, point) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = point;
        el.appendChild(li);
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderPoints();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.renderPoints();
    }

    renderPoints() {
        const el = this.refs.points;
        el.innerHTML = '';
        this.props.points.forEach(function(point) {
            ExternalLib.addPoint(el, point);
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render')
        return (
            <div>
                <ul ref="points"></ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            points: []
        };
    }

    addPoint() {

        const points = this.state.points.slice();

        points.push((new Date()).getTime());

        this.setState({
            points: points
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addPoint.bind(this)}>Add Point</button>
                <Child points={this.state.points} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This is simplified because in this example I could generate the markup directly making use of *map* and leveraging React's partial DOM update - the external lib does some extra stuff that's not in this question's scope.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interfere with React rendering process, you can code [shouldcomponentupdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

In your children, if you make `shouldcomponentupdate` return `false` and call `ExternalLib.addPoint(point)`, it should do the job:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
  //comparePoints() is a function able to find if a new point is present in the list, comparing existing used points with new one
  var newPoint = comparePoints(this.props.points, nextProps.points)

  if(newPoint){
    ExternalLib.addPoint(newPoint);
    //forbide re-render
    return false;
  }

  //enable other update
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @damien-leroux! Yes, I can check the point's uniqueness. This seems like a nice way to add points and prevent the full re-render as well.